# Can we PUT a data to Azure Event Hub using OAuth

Tags: azure, http, oauth, azure-eventhub

Is there a way to send the data to Azure Event Hub via http call using OAuth rather than Generating a SAS token?

Comment: Is this referring to SAS the programming application/language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Event Hubs REST endpoints support [authorization via Azure Active Directory token](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest#common-headers).  Azure Active Directory does offer support for [OAuth flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), so I believe this is possible.

To be pedantic, the answer to your question is technically "no" since [sending an event via REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/send-event) is a POST operation, not PUT.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I agree we need to use POST operation. I will try to perform the operation with the help of links above.